# Как получить реферальную ссылку telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram

https://t.me/brobotmebot?start=ref403295577 - пример Brobot, как в коде получить данные  start. Использую telegram Api пишу на php

Answer (score 1):

Например вот так:

```
$url = 'https://t.me/brobotmebot?start=ref403295577';
$queryParams = [];

$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $queryParams);

if (isset($queryParams['start'])) {
    echo $queryParams['start'];
}
```